# Missing DataValidation DataSource

Tags: excel

I am working on an excel spreadsheet. I have a dropdown with values. I need to add a value in there.

There is no macro and there is no connection. The only thing I found was:

1. I selected the cell at hand
2. Data -> DataValidation
3. In the source i can see this string =Variables!$D$1:$D$23

I do not have a sheet called variables or anything close to the word variables in any of the sheets. Where can this be coming from?

There is also protection on the workbook but not the individual sheets. Could this be the issue?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked if there is a sheet called "Variables" that is hidden? If there is nothing there, open the VBA editor and see if there is a module for a "Variables" sheet there, as you can set sheets to a "Very Hidden" state that doesn't show up in the Excel UI as well.

Comment: Yes, when I try to open the macros i can see 3-4 other sheets which are not displayed. The workbook is protected. I tried to run one of those macros that are supposed to show you a usable password, but it didnt work. Even tried renaming the file extension to xls (older excel versions) but it just stops responding. I wait for about 20 min, no progress and I close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually check the contents of a hidden sheet quite easy using the Immediate Window.

So open the VBA editor (Alt-F11), go to the Immediate window (Ctrl-G), and try:

```
?Variables.[D17]
```

If this works, you can repeat this to see the other 22 validation values (or write a small sub, using `Debug.Print` ubstead of `?`).